# How to write function for multiple textboxes in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, textbox

I am writing code for validating the money value as

```
       function monyValid()
       {

       var valw=document.getElementById("<%=txtID4.ClientID%>").value;
       var regex  = /(?:^\d{1,3}(?:\.?\d{2})*(?:,\d{2})?$)|(?:^\d{1,3}(?:,?\d{3})*(?:\.\d{2})?$)/            
       if (!isNaN(valw) && isFinite(valw)) 
       {
         document.getElementById("<%=txtID4.ClientID%>").value=parseFloat(valw).toFixed(2);
       }           
         if (regex.test(valw))
         {          
           alert("valid");
         }
         else
         {
           alert("Number is invalid");
         }
       }
```

now I want to apply the same validation to multiple textboxes. How can I use the same function for different textboxes. I want something like

```
      function monyValid(txtVal)
       {           
       var valw=document.getElementById(txtVal).value;
       }
```

How can I implement this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass in `this` and use it as a parameter in the function instead of calling `document.getElementById`.

**JavaScript**

```
function monyValid(item) {
    var valw = item.value;
    var regex = /(?:^\d{1,3}(?:\.?\d{2})*(?:,\d{2})?$)|(?:^\d{1,3}(?:,?\d{3})*(?:\.\d{2})?$)/
    if (!isNaN(valw) && isFinite(valw)) {
        item.value = parseFloat(valw).toFixed(2);
    }
    if (regex.test(valw)) {
        alert("valid");
    } else {
        alert("Number is invalid");
    }
}
```

**HTML usage**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtID4" runat="server" onFocus="onEnter(this)" onblur="onLeave(this);monyValid(this);" TabIndex="4"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: I called the function as 

 <asp:TextBox ID="txtID4" runat="server"  onFocus="onEnter(this)" 
                        onblur="onLeave(this);monyValid("<%=txtID4.ClientID%>");" TabIndex="4"></asp:TextBox>

giving error as 

Error 12 Server tags cannot contain <% ... %> constructs.

Comment: Ah you're using it like that. I changed the answer, think that should work.